# How to stop assignment of numbers to hostnames?

Tags: macos, network

My devices, including airport stations, keep being assigned a number following their name (i.e. "ATV (3)"). I was hoping Mavericks would fix it but it did not.

Is this fixable, please?

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a problem with your router. Try forcing your hostname with `scutil`:

```
scutil --set HostName yourhostname
```

### Why the number?

The bracketed numbers appear because the same Bonjour/ZeroConf name is being used multiple times on the network. If Bonjour detects a duplicate name, a number is appended to ensure uniqueness.

This does not indicate a serious problem. Resetting network caches and devices should help clear out the now superseded name.

Apple's [Bonjour Frequently Asked Questions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/faq.html) page discusses this behaviour:

> #### 12. What should happen when two devices on the network both use the same service name?
>
> In the rare case where a name collision occurs, your device should add
>   a digit to the end of the name, for example:
>
> `"Apple Mac mini (2)"`